# retrieve the value of hidden column of grid view on submit button click

Tags: asp.net

How can I retrieve the value of hidden column of grid view on submit button click. I searched on internet but mostly found methods on row button click.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridBilling">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField Visible="false" DataField="ID"/>                                        
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S No." ItemStyle-Width="8%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        ... other fields ommitted
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<div style="width:100%"><asp:Button ID="btn_SubmitGrid" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" OnClick="btn_SubmitGrid_Click" /></div>

protected void btn_SubmitGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                int iRowCnt = 0;
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridBilling.Rows)
                {
                    dr = dt_mnthlybilling.NewRow();


                    dt_mnthlybilling.Rows.Add(dr);
                    iRowCnt += 1;
                }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set visible to false on the hidden field, then you can't access it in the back-end code. This is because the data doesn't get rendered. However you can do do by accessing the dataKeys. Set the DataKeyNames on GridView. e.g:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridBilling" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
```

Then in code you can retrieve the value as

GridBilling.DataKeys[*ROW_INDEX*].Value; // This should return an object. I believe you can set to multiple keys (per row).

Alternatively you hide the column with css (on both header and item)

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
```

Css add:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .hidden
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```

In back-end code, the bound column can be accessed as

```
GridBilling.Rows[*ROW_INDEX*].Cells[0].Text; // If you have a html control you can replace text with FindControl("control_name")
```

Also in your cs code you have a call to NewRow(). If you accessing a row then you should be calling *row*. eg:

```
int iRowCnt = GridBilling.Rows.Count;

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridBilling.Rows)
{
    // row.Cells[0].Text
    dt_mnthlybilling.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

*(It's been years since I've done web forms, so the syntax may be slightly incorrect.)*